# Disambiguate [ziparchive]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [ziparchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ziparchive) tag-wiki only refers to a PHP extension but other things are also named the same, notably a new class in .NET 4.5 for handling zip archives (System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive).

Maybe the tag should be split to indicate the platform?

Comment: Stumbled across this when doing some research on this tag; there's a newer post that's basically a dupe to this: [Tag \[ZipArchive\] is for PHP but used on numerous C# questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389180). I suspect the newer version has a greater chance of being taken up again.