# What should be done about [zip] and similar tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I came across a question wrongly tagged with [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip). While the tag referred to *data compression*, the question referred to the `zip` function (which conjoins two lists into one list of pairs; often found in languages with some support for functional-programming e.g. Python or Haskell).

I was trying to find a tag which refers to the `zip` function but couldn't find one. A lot of questions seem to be mis-tagged with [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip).

[zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip)

> ZIP is a format for compressed file archives, allowing packaging of multiple files and directories into a single file.

This tag can be misinterpreted to refer to `zip` (a function that conjoins two lists into one list of pairs; often found in languages with some support for functional-programming such as Python or Haskell). For example:

- [Python zip-like function that pads to longest length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277278/python-zip-like-function-that-pads-to-longest-length).
- [Can I zip more than two lists together in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664439/can-i-zip-more-than-two-lists-together-in-scala)

On further research, it's not just [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip) that seems to have issues. A couple other tags with issues are outlined below.

[zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipfile)

> For issues relating to creating and/or utilizing zip files.

This one is less likely to be misunderstood and hence, less likely to be misused. But the description and wiki aren't as sophisticated as that of [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip). I don't understand why two separate tags are needed. Possible synonym to [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip).

[ziparchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ziparchive)

> ZipArchive is a PHP extension for manipulating zip compressed archives

The description suggests that this tag should be used for questions referring to the PHP extension. However, this tag is also misinterpreted.

- [Unable to Extract ZIP Files Created From Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55246018/unable-to-extract-zip-files-created-from-java). Asked March 2019. Java, no reference to PHP.
- [Overwriting File in ZipArchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653768/overwriting-file-in-ziparchive). Asked January 2011. Python, no reference to PHP.

<sup>Additionally, there is [php-zip-archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-zip-archive) (39 Questions, no usage guidance, no wiki). Possible synonym to [ziparchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ziparchive).</sup>

**Looking at all these misinterpretations and mis-tags, it seems like these tags need substantial clean-up effort. What should we do with these?** Synonymising and disambiguating look like promising options...

---

Nota Bene:

- As of this writing, [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip), [zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipfile), and [ziparchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ziparchive) have no synonyms. They're not even aliased to each other!
- A list of tags with tag names containing `zip` can be found here: [Data.SE Query – Tags with zip](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1017120/1256304/tags-with-name-containing-zip). Some of these are language-specific (e.g. [jszip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jszip)). Some of these have no tag-wiki (e.g. [zipwith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipwith)). Some of these could also be burninated/removed? Especially those with less than 10 questions.
- It irks me that I still couldn't find a tag that refers to the `zip` function. Even after browsing through the tags from the Data.SE query. ([zipwith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipwith) comes close to this but it's a different function.) Perhaps [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip) should be dedicated to the function and [zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipfile) dedicated to data compression...
- A similar situation is present with **map**. There is the data structure ([map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map), aliased to [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary)) then there is the higher-order function ([map-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map-function)). Following this, perhaps [zip-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zip-function) could be created for questions related to the zip function and not zip files.
- Related, but unanswered: [Disambiguate [ziparchive]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291675/disambiguate-ziparchive)

Comment: I think it should be disambiguated.

Comment: While I appreciate the time you spent looking all the tags up, I disagree with the notion of needing a dedicated `zip-function` tag. There are already some function tags ([tag:sin], [tag:cos] other trigonometric functions) but all have low usages, are only appliccable with a language tag, useless alone. zip works diffrent in python 2, python 3 or haskel - you can not be a specialist in all unless you mastered all the languages. We can not have a tag for every function that is common in 2 or more languages - they do not get used anyhow. As for aliassing/disambiguating: that sounds fine.

Comment: Let's globally rename the `zip` function to `interleave`. We should be able to get all those standards bodies on board, right?

Comment: My feelings about a potential [zip-function] tag are lukewarm at best -- it looks too fine-grained to me. (As you note, [map-function] already exists, but I'd say that is a special case, as `map` is an exceptionally important function.) In any case, disambiguating [zip] so that it becomes about file compression alone would be a sensible thing to do.

Comment: As far as disambiguation goes, both [tag:zip] and [tag:zipfile] clearly and specifically mention "files" and/or "directories". Like I mentioned in the post, these two seem like glaring synonyms. One change I'd make to the descriptors though, is to add a "**Do not use this tag to refer to the zip function or X or Y.**" in the usage guidance.

Comment: @canon From what I'm seeing, `interleave` seems to be an entirely different function... the terms don't seem to be interchangable. (Tbh, I couldn't tell whether or not your comment was meant to be sarcastic. :P)

Comment: As I [recently learned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381483/803359): *If you can't even research what an NPE is and do really basic debugging tricks to figure out what is causing it, you are nowhere near ready to ask questions on Stack Overflow*. So shouldn't one also expect that users are capable of reading --- including tag-descriptions?

Comment: @mikuszefski Eek, it's kind of spooky to see yourself be quoted right when you're looking at the space the quote appears in. You are correct we should be able to assume that. But that doesn't stop people from applying wrong tags, just like people are not stopped from asking questions without investing the proper amount of study into it first.

Comment: @Gimby. True, but I guess that remains independent of the effort spent to disambiguate, to rearrange tags, etc. ...so work done probably in vain. Although, a cleaned up tag set surely is appreciated by users who know how to use them anyway.

Comment: @TrebledJ is there actually an interleave function? I was being facetious. :P

Comment: @mikuszefski I think, counter to thinking of it as being work being done in vain, cleaned up tags hosting relevant questions make it easier for questions to be found (e.g. through the search bar). Moreover, the work _should_ pay off – we'd be improving the quality of StackOverflow after all.

Comment: @canon Haha, I found this: [haskell - Interleave function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772235/interleave-function) but I see what you did. :P

Comment: I think tags and titles can complete each other, e.g: How I can zip a file? with `zip` as its tag is okay, but Working with ZIP? with `zip` as its tag is not clear enough. also I agree with @PatrickArtner, it's almost impossible _and useless_ to have tag for everything.

Comment: @TrebledJ Agreed, just as I mentioned in the second part of my comment.