# Tag [ZipArchive] is for PHP but is used on numerous C# questions

Tags: support, tags, tag-disambiguation

There is a .NET [class in System.IO.Compression called ZipArchive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive) which gets asked about in C# questions, but people [are using the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ziparchive+c%23) [ziparchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ziparchive) which is for an unrelated PHP library.

How can we split these cases up or otherwise disambiguate them?

---

Here are all the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) + [ziparchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ziparchive) cases, all of which appear to deserve a different tag:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+ziparchive

---

When this question was first asked, the amount of [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) questions was small, but today there's 97 of them.

Can we clean this up in some way, so that the PHP and C# usages are both accommodated without misusing an existing tag?

Comment: Not a problem, you can count the number of questions that don't disambiguate with the primary tag ([php] or [c#]) on the fingers of one hand.  Even after an unfortunate industrial accident.  In the unlikely case that somebody forgot to use it then just add it.

Comment: [75 C#](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bziparchive%5D+%5Bc%23%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0), over [400 PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bziparchive%5D+%5Bphp%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0) - splitting it seems like a good idea.

Comment: Three years on in 2022, we're up to 783 questions with the [[tag:ziparchive]] tag, with 97 of them also tagged [[tag:c#]]; I think clean up and disambiguation still makes sense today. We should take another related tag, [[tag:php-zip-archive]] into this conversation too. The usage of that one appears to be split somewhat between PHP questions about ZipArchive and PHP questions about zip archives/ other related tools.